# How to interpret linear regression results in nonparametric data?

Tags: regression, linear, spearman-rho

I performed a correlation analysis using Spearman's correlation coefficient and found 4 factors say A,B,C,D are significant. I used regression analysis also and found that 3 factors B,C,D are significant. On multiple regression, I found 2 factors B,C are significant. Now my question is that how can I interpret my results now? Can linear regression be applied to the non-parametric analysis? How to explain the variation in Simple regression (significance level)
and significance level after correlational analysis? All the independent and dependent variables are continuous.

Comment: Data are neither parametric nor nonparametric; those are adjectives that apply to models or techniques. If you mean "not normally distributed" that's not at all the same thing as "nonparametric". Alternatively if you mean something like "the data are categorical", that is also not the same as "nonparametric" Please amend your post to more clearly express the actual situation.

Answer (score 1):

A nonparametric regression model simply avoids the assumption of normal or any other parametric distribution as the distribution for the error term.

Comment: Linear regression does not impose normality, in fact it imposes very few assumptions on the error term if you opt for robust methods.

Comment: @Repmat I think the key phrase is "if you opt for robust methods." Linear regression often (usually?) does assume normality to facilitate inference.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your multiple regression gives different results from a series of simple regression models is that it takes into account the inter-relationship between the predictor variables. In a sense if it did not give different results at least some of the time it would not be worth having in our armamentarium.

Comment: Thanks, so you mean the result of multiple regression is final and binding?